# How to assign object to ref

Tags: nim-lang

This code fails to compile:

```
var s: ref string = nil
s = ref "hi"
echo s
```

The error is `(2, 9) Error: type expected, but got: "hi"`. I've tried putting `ref` and `ptr` in front and back of the string, tried to find some example in the documentation, but failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var s: ref string
new(s)
s[] = "hi"
echo s[]
```

- Declare
- Allocate new object
- Assign to dereferenced string
- Echo final string in dereferenced form

Note that `echo s[]` is needed because `ref string` does not implement `$` operator, and cannot be converted to string by echo.

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure why you want to do this. But first you need to create your ref type, then assign the value to a string. Something like this:

```
var s: ref string = nil
echo s.repr
new s
s[] = "hi"
echo s[]
echo s.repr
```

Will output something like this:

```
nil
hi
ref 0x7f7d4bbcf050 --> 0x7f7d4bbd2090"hi"
```

But as I said, not sure why you'd want this. Strings are already a reference type. As long as you pass them as mutable to a procedure you will be able to modify the underlying data:

```
var s: string = ""
s = "hi"
echo s
echo s.repr

proc test(x: string) =
  echo x.repr

proc testM(x: var string) =
  echo x.repr
  x[1] = 'o'
  
test s
testM s

echo s
echo s.repr
```

Will output something like:

```
hi
0x7f5fc2807060"hi"
0x7f5fc2807060"hi"
0x7f5fc2807060"hi"
ho
0x7f5fc2807060"ho"
```

Comment: Is it worth pointing out that the assignment operator always copies strings here, so `s` is a _copy_ of the string literal `"hi"` in the second example?

Comment: when using arc/orc string literals are not copied or destroyed, ref https://github.com/nim-lang/RFCs/issues/221